# Drawnow on Matlab: It store the figure or store the variable?

Tags: matlab, plot, drawnow

May you please help me on a question on DRAWNOW in Matlab?

When we using `drawnow` in Matlab, what happens inside?

It stores the **figure of the previous-graph**, then plot the next-part-of-graph on the **same figure**?

OR it forgets the whole previous-graph and plot the **actual-new-graph** (with both previous and next-part)?

The both methods show the same effect: *a dynamic graph*. But I want to know exactly what happens inside.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`drawnow` makes sure that MATLAB stops doing whatever its doing and draws in the screen.

If you do

```
hold on
for ii=1:1000
   plot(ii,rand(1)); % assume complicated maths here
end
```

MATLAB will run the code and send the `plot` calls to the graphics engine. However, MATLAB is too busy running the loop to be drawing, as the code has priority over the plot.

If you do

```
hold on
for ii=1:1000
   plot(ii,rand(1));
   drawnow; % Take a break, draw everything that you must before continuing
end
```

Then, as the comment says, you temporarily stop the execution of the code, to draw everything in the graphics pipeline, and then continue executing the code.

`drawnow` has no influence in the fact that the figure is stored or not, that is the job of `hold on`.

If you are worried about redrawing the whole thing, then make sure you have a look at `set` and `get` methods for graphics. With them you can `get` the `xdata`, modify it, and `set` it again, by ensuring that the graphics engine does not redraw/recompute anything else.

---

Documentation for the `hold` function:

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html

Comment: Thanks for your quickly support.

Comment: @ThienNhat you are welcome. Consider accepting the asnwer as valid if it helped you

Comment: I should take a time to look your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Your examples are nice. My question arises when I use `drawnow` package in Python. In Python, it seems to forget any point, although the figure is still _hold on_. So I have to redraw the old-data.

Comment: @ThienNhat This question is tagged "MATLAB" so everyone assumes is about it! Ask the same question about python with the right tag, maybe someone expert on that can tell you more ;)

Comment: @AnderBiguri MATLAB is also explicitly stated in the question too! It's possible the OP meant `matplotlib` - the Python plotting library...